# Get device info with jmf

Tags: java, device, capture, jmf

I want to get information from my webcam using jmf. I'm using this code:

```
CaptureDeviceInfo deviceInfo = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice("USB2.0 UVC1.3M Webcam");
System.out.println(deviceInfo);
```

Why is the result null?

Comment: Have you tried JMF Registry to detect devices from Capture Devices?

Comment: Yes JMF Registry detect the device but i can't get any infos.

Comment: Does JMF Registry print any format entries for your device?

Comment: No.Only the name find nothing else.